# Html Text Input Element - Disable Mac Double Space to Insert Period

Tags: html, macos

For an html text input element:

```
<input type='text'>
```

Can you disable Mac OS's double space to insert period feature in that input element? For example, if I press <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> in a standard text input box, a period is inserted after `a`:

[image]

For some types of text input, such as code, this behavior is not desirable even if a user has the feature enable on their system

Comment: Matt, did you manage to figure this one out?

Comment: No, the only answers posted so far have been about changing the system-wide setting which does not address this question

Comment: Ideally there would be an input element attribute that controlled this, however it does not appear that any of autocomplete, autocorrect, autocapitalize, or spellcheck have any effect on this behavior. Relevant VSCode Issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/109047

Comment: Is there some way to disable this in a per-app basis? I would like to disable this in VS Code...

Answer (score 2):

This is an macOS system setting. On Sierra, you can turn it off by unchecking `System Preferences` > `Keyboard` > `Text` > `Add period with double-space`.

[image: Keyboard Preference Screen Capture]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a way to disable this behavior regardless of a user's settings

Comment: This was helpful to me, however.

Answer (score 2):

I have done some digging around, and what I have found so far is that normally, when a value is written in an input-field, the field experiences the following JavaScript-events (in the following order):

1. "keydown"
2. "keypress"
3. "keyup"

.. but when macOS automatically replaces double-spaces with a period, which happens when text in the input-field is followed by two taps on the space-bar in rapid succession (i.e. the input-field cannot be empty), the "keypress" event doesn't fire, and only the following events occur:

1. "keydown"
2. "keyup"

This means that even though it's probably a horrible solution, it is possible to detect the change, e.g. by keeping an eye of the last `action` and taking action in the `keyup` event if the previous event wasn't `keypress`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>macOS prevent period/full stop on double-space</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body dir="ltr">

    <div>

        <input type="text" style="width: 50%;" value="text followed by period. Add double-space after this" autofocus />

    </div>

</body>

<script>

    var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0],
        action;

    input.addEventListener("keydown", function (e){

        //Open the key-event group
        console.group("key event start", {
            code: e.code,
            keyCode: e.keyCode
        });

        console.group("keydown");
        console.log({
            e: e
        });

        action = e.type;

        console.groupEnd();
    });

    input.addEventListener("keypress", function (e){
        console.group("keypress");
        console.log({
            e: e
        });

        action = e.type;

        // console.log("value", e.target.value);

        console.groupEnd();
    });

    input.addEventListener("keyup", function (e){
        console.group("keyup");
        console.log({
            e: e
        });

        if (action != "keypress" && e.keyCode == 32 && e.target.value.endsWith(". ")) {
            console.warn("keypress action has been skipped, space-bar has been pressed and the input ends with '. '");

            e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(new RegExp(". " + "$"), " ");
        }

        console.groupEnd();

        //Close key-event group
        console.groupEnd();
    });

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: actually the only way I managed to handle this behavior is with "keypress" !!

Answer (score 0):

**In React**

I found that when the double space period happens, the `event.nativeEvent.data` is `". "` (and the `event.nativeEvent.type` is `"input"`.  On a normal key press, the data is just a single character.

The order of the events on a double space period is

```
onchange
keydown
keyup
```

So, in a controlled component, you'll need to prevent setting your value in the onChange handler.

**In vanilla JS**

The 'input' event has the `data` property that is equivalent to the React `event.nativeEvent.data` above, and the order of events on a double spaced period is

```
input
keydown
keyup
```

Normally the events are

```
keydown
keypress
input
keyup
```

Answer (score -2):

Go to System Preferences >> keyboard >> Text.
Then uncheck the option "Add period with double-space".

This option is much useful in iPhone because when we're texting the "." doesn't come in the 1st keyboard layout. But on mac we can live without it.

Comment: This just repeats @AndrewKS' answer